# DataTemplate within a DataTemplateSelector referencing the parent DataTemplateSelector?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have ListView with different properties I'd like to display, some of which are Lists themselves. These sub-lists will use the same DataTemplates as the ones in the parent list (but be indented).

Is there a way to have the child List (though I'm using an ItemsControl so I don't have to worry about scrolling) presenter refer to the DataTemplateSelector it is being defined in?

Such as:

```
<ListView ItemTemplateSelector={StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}.../>

<selectors:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector">
    <selectors:MyDataTemplateSelector.ListTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Referring to the selector it is being defined in -->
                <ItemsControl ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </selectors:MyDataTemplateSelector.ListTemplate>
</selectors:MyDataTemplateSelector>
```

It compiles fine, but seems to crash on load with an error in Windows.UI.Xaml. I assume it's because it's a circular reference. Is it possibly done with a `TemplatedParent` binding? I've been trying some different configurations, but they don't seem to be working.

Comment: It looks bad. Try create a copy of selector with different name to confirm the circular reference problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get this working as intended, but ended up getting around it another way. This won't be extensible to all methods. I've basically created a 2-depth tree. What I was looking for was a method that would work for any depth tree, but could not find an ideal one. It will likely need a custom control. However, I do have an answer for a 2-depth tree.

Using the `ListView`, I grouped the items by the top nodes, then use my selector both for the templates of the `GroupHeaderTemplateSelector` and the `ItemTemplateSelector`.

I think it may be possible to extend this out to an N-Depth Tree by making each level a Group in itself and each being displayed by a `ListView`, whether or not it has items. This is probably horribly inefficient, but may work for others that need it to in a pinch. It is also possible to construct the tree in a fairly simple way using `Linq`, so there is that at least.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, and was looking everywhere for a solution to an "n" depth tree. I came up with a solution although I don't especially like my solution, but I ended up rolling all of my sub-lists to my main level. I kept references of parents so that I would know how to display them if they had a parent.

That way I didn't need the ItemsControl inside of "MyDataTemplateSelector". Just a thought, and I was wondering what you thought of that.